# Наложить текстуру на цилиндр OpenGL / gluCylinder()

Tags: c++, opengl, текстура

Добрый день,

хочу создать цилиндр при помощи gluCylinder() (низ и верх цилиндра при помощи gluDisk), только не представляю, как потом на такие объекты накладывать текстуры. Знаю, как просто поточечно, или здесь тот же принцип, типо

```
for( ... ){
    glTexCoord2f(x, y); glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);
    ...//другие координаты
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Честно говоря, я бы не рекомендовал тебе пользоваться библиотекой GLUT. Как бы она не была хороша, у отрисовки объёмных фигур "вручную" есть ряд преимуществ:

1. **Огромный выбор фигур.** Например, в том GLUT'e, что я пользуюсь, отсутствует даже параллелепипед и эллипсоид, что говорить о других, более разнообразных фигурах вроде пирамид!
2. **Возможность оптимизации.** Думаю, пока что для тебя (да и для меня тоже) способ рисования фигур в этой библиотеке покрыт мраком. Рисуя же вручную, ты можешь применять какие угодно алгоритмы, тем самым добиваясь большей скорости работы программы.
3. **Изменяемый центр вращения.** При применении на нарисованной с помощью GLUT фигуры операций с матрицей, связанными с вращением  ( *glRotate()* ), фигура вращается только вокруг своего центра. А если необходимо будет вращать, допустим, куб вокруг одного из его углов?

   Я обладаю довольно скудными познаниями в геометрии, однако всё-таки смог месяца два назад создать код для рисования нужного тебе цилиндра. Правда, текстура накладывается несколько некорректно, да и на дне возникает такая неприятная вещь, как [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) (один полигон имеет точно такие же вершины как у другого, и в итоге при каждом обновлении сцены оба из них мерцают). Однако, надеюсь, это послужит тебе стимулом к написанию подобных функций.

   ```
   public void DrawCylinder(float x, float y, float z, float width, float 
   height, float depth, int segments)
   {
   glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
   for (int i = 0; i <= segments; i += 1)
   {
       float theta = 2.0f * (float)Math.PI * i / (segments);

       glVertex3f(width / 2 * (float)Math.Cos(theta) + x,
       y,
       depth / 2 * (float)Math.Sin(theta) + z);
       glTexCoord2f((float)Math.Cos(theta), (float)Math.Sin(theta));
       glVertex3f(width / 2 * (float)Math.Cos(theta) + x,
       height + y,
       depth / 2 * (float)Math.Sin(theta) + z);
       glTexCoord2f((float)Math.Cos(theta) * 2,
       (float)Math.Sin(theta) * 2);
   }
   for (int i = -1; i <= segments; i *= -1)
   {
       float theta = 2.0f * (float)Math.PI * i / (segments);

       glVertex3f(width / 2 * (float)Math.Cos(theta) + x,
       y,
       depth / 2 * (float)Math.Sin(theta) + z);
       glTexCoord2f((float)Math.Cos(theta),
       (float)Math.Sin(theta));
       if (i < 0)
           i -= 2;
   }
   for (int i = -1; i <= segments; i *= -1)
   {
       float theta = 2.0f * (float)Math.PI * i / (segments);

       glVertex3f(width / 2 * (float)Math.Cos(theta) + x,
       height + y,
       depth / 2 * (float)Math.Sin(theta) + z);
       glTexCoord2f((float)Math.Cos(theta),
       (float)Math.Sin(theta));
       if (i < 0)
           i -= 2;
   }
   glEnd();
   }
   ```

Переменные **x**, **y** и **z** обозначают положение фигуры в пространстве (как видишь, я просто прибавляю эти значения, тем самым перемещая каждую точку цилиндра).
**Width**, **height** и **depth** - разумеется, размер фигуры; я применяю его, умножая каждую точку на эти переменные.
Дно и верх цилиндра я рисую с помощью двух последних циклов for, чередуя координаты с одной и с другой стороны, плетя воображаемую паутину, в итоге образующую плоский круг (прошу меня извинить за неподходящие литературные сравнения).
Удачи!